# How do I set the starting position with Android MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

How do I set the starting position with Android MediaPlayer?

After I pause a track, I call `startMusic()` but rather than resuming, the MediaPlayer starts playing from the beginning.

My code:

```
public void pauseMusic() {
    if(playMusic.isPlaying()) {
        playMusic.pause();
    }

public void playMusic() {
    playMusic.start();
    playMusic.seekTo(0);
}
```

When I call `stopMusic()` it throws the following error:

```
Process: com.example.kq.meetthevwls, PID: 30166 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: That means  your "playMusic" object has been dereferenced or was never referenced in the first place. It has nothing to do with seeking.

Comment: but its playing.. resume that music but i need starting position

Comment: To get the last played position or paused position use videoView.getCurrentPosition() and to seek to last played position use videoView.seekTo(lastPlayedPosition)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error is not caused by `stopMusic()` but by the `start()` method. You probably haven't initialized the `MediaPlayer` object so when you call `start()` it crashes because the object is `NULL`.

Try with something like this:

```
playMusic = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.your_sound_name);
```

Change your activity name and the sound resource name

Comment: how this is supposed to resume the media player?

Comment: How this answer related to op's question ? - How do I set the starting position with Android MediaPlayer?

Comment: @NoorHossain if you read the stack trace OP's issue was not related to the title. You use [seekTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#seekTo(int))

Comment: The OP asked if he can start a track from position. But the answer nothing related to that.

Comment: You can user MediaPlayer.seekTo(int msecs)

Comment: @ArunK I already answered in the previous comment. If you read the stacktrace you'll understand.